# 'Cannot find -lc' error when linking a program using gcc and autoconf

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to compile a program written in C. `./configure` was successful, but when I did `make`, it gave me an error. I did `make check`, and it said:

```
gcc  -g -Wall -static   -o multipht  multipht.o multimatch.o multiweight.o multiwrite.o multisort.o multiclean.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

("multipht" is the name of the program I'm trying to install.)

Could anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Which OS? If GNU/Linux, which distro? You may need to install a package such as `glibc-static` (that's the package for Red Hat and Fedora)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system appears to not have a statically linkable C library.  That's actually pretty common these days.  Take off the `-static` flag and you should be good to go.

Comment: But if the makefile is adding the flag there may be a good reason for adding it, and it's not as simple as just removing it (editing makefiles created by automake/autoconf can be scary!)

Comment: Given OP's command line, I can't see any reason it would be there.  Why do you think it needs to be?  And editing an automake/autoconf-generated makefile is no different than editing any other makefile - just find the `-static` in there and delete it.  If OP wants to send patches back and needs to make the configure script *work*, that's a different story.  It's still not really rocket science, though.

Comment: I don't know, ask the authors of the makefile, the command line comes from running `make check` so it's not the OP's command line, it's someone else's.

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at in a more succinct form is "why would static linking ever be necessary in this case"?  Maybe this software package is just old.

Comment: @CarlNorum @JonathanWakely You mean I can just delete "-static" from the makefile? I did that and ran `make` again, but it still gave me some errors. `make check` returns: `gcc -g -Wall -o multipht multipht.o multimatch.o multiweight.o multiwrite.o multisort.o multiclean.o`  `multiweight.o: In function 'image_weights':`  `(and here's the directory of the file)/multiweight.c:66: undefined reference to 'floor'` and a couple of more similar messages

Comment: Try adding `-lm` (to link to libm which defines `floor`)

Comment: Great - sounds like you're closer.  You just need to add `-lm` as @JonathanWakely suggests.

Comment: @JonathanWakely @CarlNorum Now is it not recognizing the library it needs: `undefined reference to 'gsl_matrix_alloc'` etc. etc. The program requires the GNU Scientific Library, which I have asked our system administrator to install.

Comment: ... and *is* it installed?

Comment: Well, your `make check` line doesn't appear to have a `-l` flag for it.  Did you try adding one?

Comment: Like this: `gcc  -g -Wall -lm -l   -o solvepht  solvepht.o solveread.o solveprint.o solvematrix.o`? Now it says `gcc: solvepht: No such file or directory`

Comment: No, you have to have `-lgsl`.  What you have there is trying to link a library called `lib-o.a` (or something like that), and that's not going to work.  You should probably move the `-l` flags to the end of the command line, too.  Something like: `gcc -g -Wall -o solvepht solvepht.o solveread.o solveprint.o solvematrix.o -lm -lgsl`  You might also need a `-L/path/to/library/directory` if GSL is installed somewhere nonstandard.

Comment: So, I got some help on this. I removed the "-static" flag in the configure file, and I had to change the library directory in the makefile too so it can find the library. Now it's working! And thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora, the static version of glibc is in the `glibc-static` package.

```
sudo yum -y install glibc-devel glibc-static
```